# Notepad++ macro bug when recording several lines

Tags: notepad++

I wanted to make some notepad macro that writes several lines each time when I press the Escape key.

Something like:

```
do IF { -- 

}
THEN {

} end
```

Also, I want to do this without using a clipboard text.

I've tried to recorded it, but it doesn't work because of a cute function that helps me to writing same word that I've wrote already.

This could be the reason, I'm not sure. May be another reason... Anyway.

Can I handle it? How to paste several lines using a Notepad++ macro?

Comment: @MPI_What well then I need to copy the text every time when my clipboard is getting changed. and my clipboard is get changed constantly because what I writing is programming script. So yes It's pretty annoying >.<

Comment: What version of Notepad++ are you using?

Comment: @wonea version 6.7.7

Comment: Please you the latest version 6.8.8, and try again